# Logging into cygwin termninal via ssh does not wait for input on some commands

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I'm logging into a windows box via SSH.  The windows box SSH daemon is being run by MobaSSH.  MobaSSH installs its configured version of cygwin.  I'm able to do pretty much any thing I want, but in some cases when I invoke a windows shell command, and there is a prompt for interactive input to stdin, the prompt doesn't wait for my input, it always enters the default.

For example, I want to remove all the network shares for my session, so I enter:

```
net use "*" /d
```

Sure enough the question comes back from the net use command:

```
 You have these remote connections:

    P: \\192.168.1.33\proj
    Z: \\192.168.1.20\resources

 Continuing will cancel the connections

 Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]:
 No valid response was provided
```

Yet, I never entered anything into the prompt--no waiting.  It just assumed I wanted to enter in [N].  I tried to use a pipe like so:

```
net use "*" /d | Y
```

and

```
net use "*" /d | "Y"
```

But then I just get the message:

```
No valid response was provided
```

without any listing of my network shares.

Any suggestions so I can actually get rid of the network connections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out how to solve the issue.  I had to run the command with the cmd /c "" to get it to work properly in the cygwin terminal.

I did

```
cmd /c "net use * /d"
```

And sure enough, I was able to interact with the prompt.